# Error when updating a custom field in a custom object - Attempt to de-reference a null object Error

Tags: apex, update, null-pointer

I am trying to update a field in a custom object and I have stripped back my code to the bare minimum.  I am getting this error on submission when I click the save button.  How do I fix it?

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!save}' in component  in page inputfieldhelloworld: Class.leadershipReadyCon.save: line 24, column 1
>
> Class.leadershipReadyCon.save: line 24, column 1

Here is my APEX Class

```
public with sharing class leadershipReadyCon {

// After declaring final you can not modify any record.    
//public final Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady;

// getter and setter required to access and update record field from page.
public Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady {get;set;}
PageReference ref = new PageReference('&message=hello%20world');


 //Constructor function
public leadershipReadyCon() {
   //Initialize  first to avoid null error.
    Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady  = new Leadership_Ready__c();

    // if there is any record found then it will assign to myLeadershipReady otherwise we have already Initialize it.
     for(Leadership_Ready__c  lr : [SELECT Id, Automated_TP_Status__c FROM Leadership_Ready__c  WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodId')]){ 

    }

}// End Constructor function

public PageReference save(){  
    update myLeadershipReady;
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    return ref;  
} 

}
```

Here is the VFP

```
<apex:page controller="leadershipReadyCon" tabStyle="Leadership_Ready__c">

<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Automated Training Plan Status">
       <!-- You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!Leadership_Ready__c.Automated_TP_Status__c}"/>
             Always you your variable not the object as you can see in code below.
           -->
        Your Status: <apex:inputField value="{!myLeadershipReady.Automated_TP_Status__c}" />

        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declared local variable as the same name in the Constructor

```
Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady  = new Leadership_Ready__c();
```

That's why during `save`, class level `myLeadershipReady` variable is null.

Just corrected the code:

```
public with sharing class leadershipReadyCon {

    // After declaring final you can not modify any record.    
    //public final Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady;

    // getter and setter required to access and update record field from page.
    public Leadership_Ready__c myLeadershipReady {get;set;}
    PageReference ref = new PageReference('&message=hello%20world');


     //Constructor function
    public leadershipReadyCon() {
       //Initialize  first to avoid null error.
        myLeadershipReady  = new Leadership_Ready__c();

        // if there is any record found then it will assign to myLeadershipReady otherwise we have already Initialize it.
         for(Leadership_Ready__c  lr : [SELECT Id, Automated_TP_Status__c 
            FROM Leadership_Ready__c  
            WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodId')]){ 
            myLeadershipReady = lr;
        }

    }// End Constructor function

    public PageReference save(){  
        update myLeadershipReady;
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;  
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Boral, that fixed that issue but now it is coming up with a different error:  
>System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Error is in expression '{!save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page inputfieldhelloworld: Class.leadershipReadyCon.save: line 24, column 1

Class.leadershipReadyCon.save: line 24, column 1

Comment: you need to structure the code properly. From the SOQL query you are retrieving `Leadership_Ready__c` record. Hopefully this record should be updated. correct? updated the code. Now properly structure your code

Comment: That is working now, it updates the object but I am still getting an error.  Visualforce Error
Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.

Comment: Yes you were very helpful.  I think that the error is in this bit: PageReference ref = new PageReference('&message=hello%20world');